# Page contains from many component turn blank when reload page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a newbie in React js and currently i'm building a layout that contains from many components

For example, a home page layout that contains sidebar component, topbar component, footer component and main content component.

When i click on a link in sidebar component, the main content will be changed based on url of link i clicked on and other components will be same on all pages regardless of url.

Here is my code:

MainLayout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';  

import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';
  
const MainLayout = ({children, ...rest}) => {  
  return (  
    <div className="page page-dashboard">  
      {/* <div className="sidebar"><Sidebar></Sidebar></div>   */}
      <div className="main">
        {children}
      </div>  
    </div>  
  )  
}  
  
const MainLayoutRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {  
  return (  
    <Route {...rest} render={matchProps => (  
      <MainLayout>  
          <Component {...matchProps} />  
      </MainLayout>  
    )} />  
  )  
};  
  
export default MainLayoutRoute;
```

MainPage.js

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';  

import  Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import  Header from './Header';
import  Footer from './Footer';

import UsersList from './UsersList';

export default class MainPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <div>
              <Header/>
              <Sidebar/>
              <div className="wrapper">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path={"/users"} component={UsersList} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
              <Footer></Footer>
              
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';  

export default class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidenav">
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/users">Users</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/settings">Setting</Link></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
        );
    }
}
```

UserList.js

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom';  

export default class UsersList extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
           <button><Link to="/newuser">Add new user</Link></button>
           </div>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';  
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import './css/custom.scss';

/** Layouts **/  
import LoginLayoutRoute from "./layouts/LoginLayout";  
import MainLayoutRoute from "./layouts/MainLayout";  
  
/** Components **/  
import MainPage from './components/MainPage';  
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage'  

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>  
        <Switch>  
          <Route exact path="/">  
            <Redirect to="/login" />  
          </Route>  
          <LoginLayoutRoute path="/login" component={LoginPage} />  
          <MainLayoutRoute path="/home" component={MainPage} />
        </Switch>  
      </Router>  
    );
  }
 
}
```

But when i refresh the page, it turned blank like this:

[Before i refresh page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UacGp.png)

[After i refresh page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKIpO.png)

How can i fix this ?

Comment: If you go to developer tools -> console, are there errors?

Comment: there are no errors in console. I found that the main layout didn't render the component when i reload page

Comment: my app has two layout: Sign in Layout and Main Layout and i put two of them inside App.js as you see in my code above. The main layout has 4 components: sidebar, topbar, footer, main content. When i click on item in the sidebar, the main content will change based on item that i clicked on.